# Can we force user to 'Like' a fan page from our facebook application?

Tags: facebook, policy

everyone. I hope my question will not waste your time.

Does Facebook allow us to force a user to 'Like' a Fan Page (which is not relate to the Facebook application)? In my case, user can click 'Like' button to get more attack point in the game. In my idea there are 2 cases:

1. Provided only 'Like' button, this forces user to click 'Like' a Fan page without another option.
2. Provided 'Like' button and 'No, thank' button. This provides user 2 options to go.

I want the first option. The application also describe the detail of Fan Page.

Can I do this without harm Facebook's policy?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming

Answer (score 0):

Is attack point OPTIONAL? If you're forcing them to like to just use your application it's not like you would get many users.